# Asynchronous image downloader error Obj-c SDWebimage

Tags: uitableview, asynchronous, sdwebimage

Im working in a simple app that shows products in a tableview, i get the data from a json api. the problem is the table get laggy because of synchronous download of the images. im trying to use SDWebimage framework to solve this but i get this error:

"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "

the code i have is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"description"];

    //old synchronous code
   /* NSString *path = [[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"images"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"thumb"] valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *ruta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://18.221.78.126/ecoferia%@",path];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ruta];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    */

    //trying to do asynchronous download of the images
    NSString *path = [[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"images"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"thumb"] valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *ruta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://18.221.78.126/ecoferia%@",path];
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ruta]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

also i have the SDWebimage installed in my proyect and imported in the .m file like this:

```
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

im super new to objective-c so all the tips are appreciated.

REGARds..

Answer (score 0):

The solution was put $(inherited) in Build Settings -> Other Linker flags.
Working good :)